# In Rapidminer once I import a data set how do I change the type of a column?

Tags: data-mining, rapidminer

I've imported a datset into Rapidminer 5 and one of the columns that was supposed to be nominal or polynomial was set as a numeric. My data set has over 500 attributes so I don't really want to have to reimport my data every time I realize I've made a mistake like this. Is there some way to either automate the import process so that it saves the column types I set each time or can I go back and edit my already imported data set attribute types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add this operator to your process, after you load the data:

Data Transformation > Type Conversion > Numerical to Polynomial

on the operator, select

attribute type filter = single
attribute = [name of your attribute]

Answer (score 2):

here you go: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov5yn.png

1. Select "***Numerical to Polynomial***"

   1. Then change "***attribute filter type***" to '***subset***' Then select attributes that you want to change.
   2. One more suggestion, you better store this output in your local repository so you dont need the conversion everytime you need the data. So, you will have both original and duplicate in your basket. :)
   3. Happy Data Mining...

Answer (score 2):

apply the 'set role function':

It's listed under operators -> data tranformations -> Name and role modification -> Set role